# create Hive tables from SAS EG

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, hadoop2

We want to check if is it possible to create Hive Tables from SAS EG.
We have tried creating reference of Hive table into SAS after specifying libraries  (code below), but that's not what we want We also googled around but still no clue about that.

`libname hdp hadoop server=db12222 port=20 schema=test user=tester password='xxx';`

Can someone please tell if it's possible to create Hive Tables from SAS EG or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using explicit pass through in SAS EG.In explicit pass through you can pretty much run Hive code. An example of code from https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/115-2012.pdf is shown below

```
 proc sql;
 connect to Hadoop <connection info>;
  exec( create external table hadoop1( x double, y string, z double) row format
 delimited fields terminated by ‘\001’ stored as textfile location
 '/tmp/hadoop1_hdfs_file') by hadoop;
 quit;
```

**Edit1**

To move data from hadoop to sas or sas to hadoop, you can use libname statement way as discussed in this link

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=p06ifxdiogaiusn1wsop0vc3frd2.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

```
  libname hdp hadoop server=db12222 port=20 schema=test user=tester 
   password='xxx';  

 data work.a;
    set hdp.mytab;
 run;

 data work.a;
    set hdp.mytab (keep=col1 col2);
where col2=10;
 run;
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate.
So with your code, I was able to create table in Hive from SAS. I also changed a bit as per our requirement. 

So as of now I am able to create table in hive from already available table in hive using SAS EG.(Code below)

`proc sql;
CONNECT TO HADOOP(user="abcd" password="xxx" server="db12222" port=20 subprotocol=hive2);
exec( create table temp.sasTest as select * from test.CHANNEL) by hadoop;
disconnect from hadoop;
quit;`


But what I am trying is to create SAS table into HIVE from SAS EG.

Is there any workaround for it.

Comment: HI Kiran,

Yes I tried that too, but i am facing other issues in that. I am getting "ERROR: Error trying to establish connection: Could not open connection to /usr/bin/tmp/hadoop1_hdfs_file. The JDBC connection string (URI) could not be handled by the driver". 
Probably i do not have access on hadoop's /tmp/ folder.  I am looking into this.